# Could not use undetected chrome Headless=True

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am using the following:

- google chrome Version **117.0.5938.132** (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Chrome driver : https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.132/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
- Undetected chrome driver version 3.5.3
- Selenium 4.13.0
- OS Windows 10 64bits

Trying to do web automation, when using headless False, everything works well, but when using headless True, I get :

"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:18424
from chrome not reachable"

Any idea how to solve?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase in UC Mode.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, run the following with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
driver.quit()
```

SeleniumBase includes a fork of undetected-chromedriver with bug fixes.

Comment: Works well, thanks a lot Michael!